# Visual Studio installer project include Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have a setup project with a few items to install (Out-of-Browser Silverlight apps).  The requirement is to create an installer with *zero* .NET dependency, that will install Silverlight if it doesn't already exist.  It also needs to run completely offline.  There doesn't seem to be a merge module or bootstrapper for Silverlight, and if I launch the installer with "/q" for a quiet install, it fails due to the other installer already in progress.  It seems like the MSI-within-MSI restriction is the problem, and the only real solution is to create my own Setup.exe to install Silverlight and then start the MSI.  Am I missing anything?  Could a custom action trigger the SL installer when the main one completes? The less work, the better!

Summary:
 - No .NET/managed
 - VS 2010, Silverlight 4

Thanks!
-Arian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is to redistribute the Silverlight runtime.  This requires a license agreement with Microsoft in order to do that.  If you want a SILENT install you may have to have more specific requirements for redistribution.  Feel free to contact me directly for a contact for redistribution.